# swap area vs swap partition

Tags: 20.04, swap, disk-management

Please someone help me in differentiating swap area and swap partition (if any).
I have made 16Gb as swap area as my RAM memory is 8Gb.
When I command `free -h` shows me 16gb as swap area but when i go to disc partition,it shows me only 3gb. why?

Comment: Post your output of `free -h`, so we can have a look. Use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1282255/edit) link below your question to post the terminal output there....

Comment: `free` shows total swap space, this may be the combination of swapfile and swap partition. Try `sudo swapon -s`. This will give swapfile and swap partition sizes separately.